# Pokemon GO Evolution Cost Calculator

Tags: code-golf, game

Tired of always wondering how many more Pokémon you need to catch to get those high-tier evolutions? Wonder no more! Now you will write a complete program or function to calculate it for you!

### The Challenge:

As input, your program will receive a list of the costs in candy to evolve a Pokémon to the next tier. (This list may be separated by any delimiter of your choosing, or as function arguments). Your program will then return or print the number of Pokémon that must be caught, including the one that will be evolved, to evolve through all the tiers given.

How do you calculate this? Like so:
1. Add up all the candy costs: `12 + 50 = 62`
2. Subtract 3 candies from the total, this being from the one Pokémon you keep for evolving: `62 - 3 = 59`
3. Divide this number by 4 (3 for catching, 1 for giving it to the Professor), always taking the `ceil()` of the result: `ceil(59/4) = 15`
4. Finally, add 1 to this total to get the total number of Pokémon you must catch, 16!

Example `Input -> Output`:

```
[4] -> 2
[50] -> 13
[12, 50] -> 16
[25, 100] -> 32
[19, 35, 5, 200] -> 65
```

### Winning:

The app has already taken up most of the space on your phone, so your program needs to be as short as possible. The complete program or function with the smallest byte count will be accepted in two weeks! (with any ties being settled by the earliest submitted entry!)

Comment: How is the output calculated?

Comment: Whoops, knew I must have forgotten something...

Comment: In the future, please use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to work out kinks in your challenges and to get feedback on them before posting.

Comment: If you want a slightly less nonsensical rationale for short code length, you could go with "because the app has almost killed your battery, you want your code to be as short as possible, so you can type it in before your battery dies."

Comment: Yes, next time I will definitely use the Sandbox first.

Comment: Can we assume it costs at least one to evolve?

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be `floor(Sum(L)/4)+1`? The current formula doesn't work for sums divisible by 4. For example `[400]` would return 100, when in reality it needs to be 101 for the extra one to evolve.

Comment: @EamonOlive I think thats fair.

Comment: And @Emigna I will rollback to my previous algorithm, which did handle that case correctly.

Comment: I hope someone posts an answer in [Go](https://golang.org/)

Comment: Shouldn't the function also take hatching eggs into account?

Comment: This should never be posted to GO.  This has almost nothing to do with how Pokemon are evolved.  As I understand the question, you are evolving different Pokemon for each item in the list.  If this is the case, for the test case of [12,50], you need to catch 4 to evolve the type that needs 12 while you need 13 to evolve the one that needs 50.  That would total 17.  If instead you are trying to say you need two different candy costs to evolve a Pokemon, this is not the way the game works. You only need one candy type to evolve one Pokemon.

Comment: Is my SILOS answer considered valid. Can I assume that no Pokemon has more than 8 evolution stages?

Comment: @Keeta: each item in the list is a cost to evolve a pokemon to the tier. A real life example would be `Gastly -> Gengar = [25,100] => 32`i.e. 32 Gastly caught are needed to evolve first to a Haunter then to a Gengar.

Comment: This doesn't take into account that you get a single candy *back* when you evolve. As in, if you have 12 candies and evolve a Pidgey (cost 12), you end up with one candy after evolution. For a test case with several evolutions like [12,12,12,12], this means you only need to catch 12 instead of the 13 yours would give as an answer. Not that any evolution chain in the actual game has that many stages... but your test cases do.

Comment: @Enigma If this were the original posters intent, there would be no requirement for more than 2 levels for the test cases.  There are no Pokemon GO characters that evolve more than twice.  With another discrepancy pointed out by Geobits, I stand by my statement that this should not be posted to GO.

Comment: @Keeta Emigna is correct about the way this challenge is supposed to work. However, I wish I had remembered the fact Geobits had pointed out, as that would make this challenge much more interesting.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Unless there is still a typo that I'm not seeing, the correct result for `[3]` is `1`.

Comment: You're missing the subtract 3 part, `3-3 = 0 -> ceil(0/4) = 0 + 1 = 1`, that should clear it up :)

Answer (score 9):

## Jelly, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
S:4‘
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Uzo04oCY&input=&args=WzE5LCAzNSwgNSwgMjAwXQ)

`S`um, integer divide `:` by `4` and increment `‘`.

Comment: ;-; I'm 4 seconds late

Comment: It doesn't work when the sum is divisible by 4.

Comment: Gives wrong answer for `[4]`.

Comment: Fixes. Apparently the spec changed when I was sleeping.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
O4÷>
```

**Explanation**

```
O    # sum
 4÷  # integer division by 4
   > # increment
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TzTDtz4&input=WzE5LCAzNSwgNSwgMjAwXQ)

Comment: ÷ is 2 bytes   ...

Comment: @user23127: 05AB1E uses the CP-1252 encoding.

Answer (score 3):

## C# REPL, 15 bytes

```
n=>n.Sum()/4+1;
```

Casts to `Func<IEnumerable<int>, int>`.

Answer (score 3):

### Actually, 4 bytes

```
Σ¼≈u
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=zqPCvOKJiHU&input=WzE5LCAzNSwgNSwgMjAwXQ)

Explanation:

```
Σ¼≈u
Σ     sum
 ¼    divide by 4
  ≈   floor
   u  add 1
```

Comment: Aren't these unicode characters 2 bytes each?

Comment: @user23127 If this were encoded in UTF-8, yes. Actually (and its predecessor Seriously) use CP437.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
+:4/+
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=Kzo0Lys&input=WzE5OjM1OjU6MjAwXQ&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

A very original answer…

```
+        Sum
 :4/     Integer division by 4
    +    Increment
```

Answer (score 2):

## BASH (sed + bc) 19

```
sed 's~)~+4)/4~'|bc
```

Input is a `+` separate list on stdin
E.g.:
`echo '(19+35+5+200)'|  sed 's~)~+4)/4~'|bc`

Answer (score 1):

## S.I.L.O.S <s>100 99</s> 103 characters + 22 for sample input

Code with testing harness.

```
set 512 52
set 513 10
GOSUB e
GOTO f
funce
a = 0
i = 511
lblE
i + 1
b = get i
a + b
if b E
a / 4
a + 1
return
lblf
printInt a
```

input as a series of set commands to modify the spots of the heap starting at spot 512. 
[Try it Online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=c2V0IDUxMiA1MgpzZXQgNTEzIDEwCkdPU1VCIGUKR09UTyBmCmZ1bmNlCmEgPSAwCmkgPSA1MTEKbGJsRQppICsgMQpiID0gZ2V0IGkKYSArIGIKaWYgYiBFCmEgLyA0CmEgKyAxCnJldHVybgpsYmxmCnByaW50SW50IGE&input=)

Comment: Just because Pokemon Go doesn't have more than 8 tiers of evolution (it actually maxes out at 3), doesn't mean you aren't required to handle larget test cases.

Comment: @Mego the spec clearly references pokemon go, and thus we can assume that all input will be valid input. I would have posted a much better version that does indeed handle newline separaated input terminated with a zero sentinel, but the TIO is currently borked

Comment: @Mego let me clarify with the OP. If this is invalid I can modify it to work for even larger test casees

Comment: This is actually a [standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1789/45941) - you're assuming rules not present in the challenge.

Comment: @Mego modified for a cost of three bytes, it now should work up to 1000's of evolutions.

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
$
¶4
.+|¶
$*
1111
```

Input is linefeed-separated.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JArCtjQKLit8wrYKJCoKMTExMQ&input=MTkKMzUKNQoyMDA)

Comment: @orlp yay for rule changes. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 17 bytes

```
(+1).(`div`4).sum
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 4 bytes

```
seeh
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=seeh&input=%5B19%2C+35%2C+5%2C+200%5D&warnings=0)

```
((sum(input)/2)/2)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
h/sQ4
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h%2FsQ4&input=%5B19%2C35%2C5%2C200%5D&debug=0)

Sum input with `sQ`, divide by 4 with `/4` and finally increment `h`.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 7 bytes

```
{:+4/)}
```

[Try it here!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=WzE5IDM1IDUgMjAwXQp7Ois0Lyl9Cgp-cA&input=)

Defines an unnamed block that expects the input on the stack and leaves the result there.
`:+` sums the list, `4/` divides the result by 4 and `)` increments that.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 22 bytes

```
floor(sum(scan())/4+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## **JavaScript, 29 Bytes**

```
x=>x.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)/4+1|0
```